# Can I fully replace VBA with Groovy's Scriptom?

Tags: vba, groovy, automation, scriptom

I have to integrate several Java applications with a system developed in C that embeds VBA for Automation. I would prefer to use Scriptom than VBA.

I do not have to integrate with any components developed in VB, just C developed components.
Can I fully replace VBA with Scriptom? Are there any gotchas that I should consider?

Thanks,

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking into this earlier today.  Scriptom uses Jacob, which is the Java COM Bridge.  Groovy In Action has an entire chapter dedicated to Scriptom and has this quote about Jacob:

> Jacob offers a generic API that can be used to access any native
>   object.

I am getting ready to use it to gather Windows Event Viewer logs, but have personally never used it before.